# Apply function on all elements of list and return a new list based on function's return type

Tags: haskell, lambda, type-mismatch, map-function

I want to apply a lambda function through a `map` on a list of vectors and be able to get a list of Booleans from the results and then compare all elements in the list of Booleans

```
lambda = (\ list x -> distance (x (5,5)) < 10) 

[(0,1),(1,6),(15,36)] ->
```

Apply the lambda on each elements,
which would give : `[True, True, False]`
and then check if all elements are `True`

I tried to do this

```
checkConvergence :: [Vector] -> Vector -> Bool
checkConvergence list y = map (\ list x -> distance (x y) < 10)  list
```

But I got this :

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type
>   [(Vector -> Vector) -> Bool]
> ```

Comment: Can you share your `distance` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three problems:

1. You want `\ x ->` instead of `\ list x ->`.
2. `map` will give you a list of `Bool`s. If you want to know if they're all true, then you need to either use `all` instead, or wrap the result in `and`.
3. Unless `Vector` is an alias for some weird function type, you probably meant `distance x y` or `distance (x,y)` instead of `distance (x y)`.

Comment: judging by their example, `type Vector = Num a => (a, a)`